# output xml using php

Tags: php, xml

I confuse about output xml using php, i want to print the raw xml

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$xml.="<entry>";
$xml.="<dataset>";
$xml.="</dataset>";
$xml.="</entry>";
print ($xml);

XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://localhost/api/dataset/11111
Line Number 3, Column 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry><dataset></dataset></entry>
                        ^
```

but when i change it using

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml="<root><name>sample_name</name></root>";
print ($xml);
```

it works but then I add the xml version and encoding info, it has error again

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$xml.="<root><name>sample_name</name></root>";
print ($xml);

XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://localhost/api/dataset/100039
Line Number 3, Column 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><name>sample_name</name></root>
```

It seems can't add the header info and can't use the string concatenation operator ??? How can i print xml like and with the header('Content-type: text/xml')

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
   <dataset>
   </dataset>
</entry>
```

I use the yii framework, actionView

```
$this->renderPartial('view',array('model'=>$model,'type'=>$type));
```

when I check this error in the source code, it can see the xml info, but have the two blank lines before??, maybe it's the reason XML parsing error, but how can i delete those blank lines? in the view.php and action function, i didn't find any echo/print blank lines.

```
 XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
    Location: http://localhost/api/dataset/11111
    Line Number 3, Column 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry><dataset></dataset></entry>
                        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ' to encapsulate your xml text so your " can be used within the text. Also use special character function so html will not think that it's a code.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry><dataset></dataset></entry>';
echo htmlspecialchars($xml, ENT_XML1);
```

I noticed your header Content-type is small letter. I don't know if it matters. Could you change to capital?

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

Comment: I changed to Content-Type, still shows XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity

Comment: did you parse the entire variable through htmlspecialchars?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
<?php
echo <<<END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
   <dataset>
   </dataset>
 </entry>
END
?>
```

Or you can do it as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
   <dataset>
<?php
  /* We can put code for something here */
?>
   </dataset>
 </entry>
```

Comment: when i add the header('Content-type: text/xml'); still has the same error